# Enable XeTeXinterchartoks only in non-sans/mono text

Tags: xetex

Is there a way automatically trigger the activation of XeTeXinterchartoks depending on if one is in `\ttfamily`, `\sffamily`, or `\rmfamily`?  There are some interchartok based kerns I want to use for my main font, but these create absolute monstrosities with my sans and mono fonts.

Comment: PS — could someone with more reputation create a `Xetexinterchartoks` or similar tag, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine `\ttfamily` (or the higher level command that you are using that uses that) to set `\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=0`   so the character classes are inactive for the same scope as the font change.

Comment: Excellente suggestion that I'm embarassed didn't immediately occur to me

Answer (score 0):

Inspired/stolen from David Carlisle's accepted answer, I implemented this in code:

```
\let\myttfamily\ttfamily
\def\ttfamily{\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=0\myttfamily\relax}
\let\myrmfamily\rmfamily
\def\rmfamily{\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1\myrmfamily\relax}
\let\mysffamily\sffamily
\def\sffamily{\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=0\mysffamily\relax}
\let\mynormalfont\normalfont
\def\normalfont{\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1\mynormalfont\relax}
```